# How to turn variable length bytes(less than 8) to long long int faster in python3?

Tags: python-3.4

I have tried to use while loop and struct.unpack to solve the problem like this:

```
import struct

def func(inputBytes):
    inputBytes = bytearray(inputBytes)
    while inputBytes.__len__() < 8:
        inputBytes.append(0)
    inputBytes.reverse()
    return struct.unpack("!q", inputBytes)[0]

print(func(b'\x00\x01'))
```

But it is too slow.How to make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've thought it too complicated before. direct calculation is faster.

```
def func(rawData):
    sum = 0
    for i in rawData[::-1]:
        sum += i
        sum <<= 8

    sum >>= 8
    return sum
```